# networking restart fails (Failed to start Raise Network Interfaces), networking ignores static ip address

Tags: networking, server

So I have a linux server running ubuntu. I set this thing up a while ago and setup a static IP and everything has been fine, up until now. Today, there was a power surge at my house and the server is now using the wrong IP address, is ignoring the /etc/network/interfaces file, and I can't restart networking.

**ifconfig**

```
ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a250:98ca:d9cc:188  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 30:85:a9:8d:fa:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 815  bytes 731980 (731.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 695  bytes 86443 (86.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 255  bytes 21586 (21.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 255  bytes 21586 (21.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Interfaces file**

```
 cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp

auto lo enp3s0
iface lo inet loopback
iface enp3s0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.7
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
```

**Resolves to two hostnames** (which doesn't make sense to me)

```
hostname -I
192.168.1.8 192.168.1.7
```

**Network restart failure**

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
[....] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.serviceJob for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

**systemctl status networking.service**

```
 systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-08-09 22:05:47 MDT; 25s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 2137 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2137 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 09 22:05:46 SilverServer dhclient[2160]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.8 from 192.168.1.1 (xid=0x7b2bf54d)
Aug 09 22:05:46 SilverServer ifup[2137]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.8 from 192.168.1.1 (xid=0x7b2bf54d)
Aug 09 22:05:46 SilverServer ifup[2137]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Aug 09 22:05:47 SilverServer dhclient[2160]: bound to 192.168.1.8 -- renewal in 37852 seconds.
Aug 09 22:05:47 SilverServer ifup[2137]: bound to 192.168.1.8 -- renewal in 37852 seconds.
Aug 09 22:05:47 SilverServer ifup[2137]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Aug 09 22:05:47 SilverServer ifup[2137]: ifup: failed to bring up enp3s0
Aug 09 22:05:47 SilverServer systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 09 22:05:47 SilverServer systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 09 22:05:47 SilverServer systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

I want the server to start up using 192.168.1.7, but I can only connect to it with putty through 192.168.1.8. I've been working on this problem for two hours now and have gotten nowhere. Please help, happy to clarify anything and happy to try anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have enp3s0 set to use dhcp AND static IP addresses.

Change your `/etc/network/interfaces` to this...

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.7
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
```